# Why do the variables in my react component disappear after a function is run?

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component that onClick runs a function. This function send a fetch request and removes something from the database and then returns the new object. This updates the UI. Up to this point everything works fine. But if I try to remove another object using the same path, the variables that should go into the path are "undefined". Why could this be?

This is the function where props.poolId and dropletId both return undefined:

```
const removeDroplet = (dropletId) => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/pools/" + props.poolId + "/" + dropletId, {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => props.updatePoolData(res)) //updates the parent component
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  };
```

This is the code where the removeDroplet function is triggered:

```
{props.droplets.map((droplet, index) => {
          return (
            <table 
              key={index}
              className="droplet-results"
              >
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td className="width-10">{index + 1}</td>
                  <td>{droplet.name}</td>
                  <td className="width-30">
                    <a className="float-right" onClick={() => removeDroplet(droplet.id)}>
                       remove
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          );
        })}
```

I was not expecting the variables props.poolId and dropletId (which is passed as a parameter) to be "undefined".

**More code**

The "updatePoolData" function has to go through a parent component as follows:

```
const updatePoolData = (data) => {
    props.updateData(data);
  };
```

And then arrives at the grandparent component where it is "updateData" and runs this:

```
const updateData = (data) => {
    if (data.pool) {
      setPool(data.pool);
    } else {
      setPool({ ...pool, ...data.createdPool });
    }
  };
```

Comment: Can you show the code for updatePoolData and give an example of what console.log(res) returns? It seems like the  updatePoolData is causing the issue if the res is not what you expect it to be.

Comment: sure. I've added the code below.

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was to change the code on the backend. Initially the response being handled was:

```
res.status(200).json({pool});
```

The solution was to change this to:

```
res.status(200).json({pool: pool.toObject({ getters: true })});
```

By using getters, React has a sign that something has changed and so refreshed the component.